# How consistent is the size of std::size_t

Tags: c++, c++11, abi, size-t

I'm writing a set of pure virtual classes that act as interfaces. The idea is that the code implementing such interfaces could be built with a different build configuration, compiler, or even a different STL implementation to code making use of such an object via such an interface.

Plain old data like `uint32_t` is standardised as is `double` and `float`. (`bool` is not since the standard does not state its size.)

Which category does `std::size_t` come in? Is it purely a function of the machine architecture? For example, on a 32 bit machine, could it ever be such that `sizeof(std::size_t)` is not 4?

Comment: The standard does not state the size of `double` and `float`.

Comment: I though it did *effectively* by stating that they are IEEE 32 and 64 bit floating point types. Perhaps I'll put in a `static_assert` to qualify my assumption.

Comment: The standard does not require `double` and `float` to be IEEE floating point types. If it required that then `numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559` would be redundant because it would always be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`size_t` is only required to be unsigned and large enough to contain the size of any object in bytes, so depending on its size is a not portable. This is covered in the draft C++ standard section `18.2` *Types* which says:

> The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type
>   that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

For integers if you need a specific width you need to use the types defined in [cstdint header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Note, the standard does not specify the size of *float* and *double*, they are not required to be *IEEE 754* floating point numbers.

Comment: +1 Many thanks, in particular for quoting the standard. That will make a useful program comment so keeping my boss happy.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, neither `double` nor `float` have standardized sizes. In fact, the only types that do are the (u)intNN_t types, and they might not exist.

So the documentation you need is not the standard, it is the target compiler documentation.

But for the purpose of stability across compilers, compiler versions, build configurations and standard libraries, it's pretty safe to assume that on any given platform, `std::size_t` has a consistent size. Note, however, that 32-bit and 64-bit builds are different platforms.